# How to emit pusher events to only specific user?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pusher, pusher-js

I want to emit pusher event from nodejs to specific client in react. If multiple clients have subscribed to the channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events are broadcast to all subscribed clients of the channel. If you need to target individual clients you should have them subscribe to their own channel and then send the event via this channel.